# Grep only the 3 characters next to open bracket

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have text  like this ,i want to grep only the 3 characters next to open bracket.
Please help.

```
condition: s(XXX_ygh_ghj_jui,00.05) | s(DFG_GHH_CN_GJ_YUI_UYT_UIJ,00.05)
condition: s(GYZ_ygh_ghj_jui,00.05) | s(TYU_GHH_CN_GJ_YUI_UYT_UIJ,00.05)
condition: s(UFG_ygh_ghj_jui,00.05) | s(QWE_GHH_CN_GJ_YUI_UYT_UIJ,00.05)
condition: s(JTH_ygh_ghj_jui,00.05) | s(YUT_GHH_CN_GJ_YUI_UYT_UIJ,00.05)
```

My desired o/p is

```
XXX DFG
GYZ TYU
UFG QWE
JTH YUT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU `grep` can do this, but if you use `grep`, it will split the matches onto multiple lines:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\()...' file
XXX
DFG
GYZ
TYU
UFG
QWE
JTH
YUT
```

As @kusalandanda suggested in the comments, you could bring them onto one line with `paste`, but that will only work if you have *exactly* two matches per line. No more and no less:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\()...' file | paste -d ' ' - - 
XXX DFG
GYZ TYU
UFG QWE
JTH YUT
```

I would instead use something like `sed` or `perl`. These solutions can deal with 1, 2 or more matches per line:

```
$ sed 's/[^(]*(\(...\)[^(]*/\1 /g' file
XXX DFG 
GYZ TYU 
UFG QWE 
JTH YUT
```

or

```
$ perl -lne '@m=(/\((...)/g); print "@m"' file
XXX DFG
GYZ TYU
UFG QWE
JTH YUT
```

Comment: Pass the output of your first command through `paste -d ' ' - -`.

Comment: @Kusalananda that would work, but only if there are _exactly_ two `(` per line. The other solutions work for any number of cases. Answer edited though, could be useful for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed 's/.*(\(...\).*(\(...\).*/\1 \2/' file
XXX DFG
GYZ TYU
UFG QWE
JTH YUT
```

The `sed` expression matches the whole line of input, but collects the three characters after each of the two left parentheses.  The line is then replaced by the two sets of collected characters, with a space in-between.

Answer (score 1):

And also with `awk` setting `FS` as `[(_]`:

```
awk -v FS='[(_]' '{print $2,$6}' file
XXX DFG
GYZ TYU
UFG QWE
JTH YUT
```

i.e., the delimiter can be a regular expression. Here it is much more examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204192/using-multiple-delimiters-in-awk

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` which works for any number of "fields" though at the expense of additional space at each end

```
sed -E "s/[c_][^(]+./ /g"  file
```

A global search which starts from `c` or `_`

```
[c_]
```

followed by anything that is not a `(`

```
[^(]+
```

plus the next character `.`, which will be either `(` or the last in a line, and replaces them with a space.

**OR**

An `awk` which is also "number of fields" agnostic

```
awk -F\( '{for (i=2; i<=$NF; i++) $(i-1)=substr($i,1,3); $NF=""}1' file
```

Set the `FS` to `(` and then cycle through the fields from the second to the last, setting field `i-1` equal to the first 3 characters of field `i` and clears the last before printing.